# Can we logout facebook programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I have facebook login in my iphone app using facebook sdk-3.1 .After login it will get in to my app and there I didnot give any logout button .so,when we click button login with facebook I will get the previous user facebook account .

Inorder to resolve this problem iam giving button logout.

how can I logout facebook programmatically on clicking button

am giving login like this

```
-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender
{

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     appDelegate.getActionForLoginbtn=@"LoginwithFB";
       [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}


-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI{


    NSArray *permissions=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
    return[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];
}
```

Comment: do you store username & token?

Comment: so , on the click event of your logout button set those to nil

Answer (score 20):

Use this code:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}
```

Comment: do you store username & token in nsuserdefults or anyware

Answer (score 5):

Swift version

`import FBSDKLoginKit`

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

Using FBSDK 4.4

```
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h>
```

then use this code to logout.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[manager logOut];
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: I see how the function works, but I guess it's a little bit strange that we need to create instance. Why they did not implement it as a static method. `setCurrentAccessToken` and `setCurrentProfile` are static as well =)