# how can logout from facebook in ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have integrated Facebook login in my app and therfore user can login with both my app account and also Facebook and do corresponding actions.

```
  -(IBAction)FacebooklogoutBtnClick:(id)sender
  {
      FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
      [loginManager logOut];
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logout from Facebook programmatically iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623191/logout-from-facebook-programmatically-ios)

Answer (score 2):

just write below line and thats it..

```
[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];
```

**OR**

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```

**OR**

```
FBSDKLoginManager *logMeOut = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[logMeOut logOut];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
            [login logOut];
 }
```

or you can use FBSession for this if you are using FBSession

```
  [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
  [[FBSession activeSession] close];
  [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
  [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```