# Logout user from facebook ios sdk from another page

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, logout

I tried `[[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];` and

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
        [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
    }
```

and this as well as

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    if ( [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ){
        [login logOut];
    }
```

but logout is not work ...any help will be appreciable Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logout from Facebook programmatically iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623191/logout-from-facebook-programmatically-ios)

Comment: How do you know logout doesn't work ? If you set a breakpoint do you go through the "if" every time ?

Comment: yes but still when i go back it gives me logging results

Answer (score 1):

[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil]; // write this code on logout button click and after that navigate to it's rootview controller or your initial view Controller

Answer (score 0):

Swift version

```
import FBSDKLoginKit

FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
```

Using FBSDK

```
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h>
```

then use this code to logout.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[manager logOut];
```

hope this will help....